# Закрыть страницу скриптом tampermonkey

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

Я немного устав вылавливать очередное творение волшебников из Mail.ru, решил написать свой скрипт, который закрывает страничку, если в адресе содержится go.mail. Скачал tampermonkey, почитал мануалы, JS вспомнил и наваял простую проверку:

```
    if (window.location.toString().indexOf("go.mail")!==-1){
        window.close();
    }
```

Все просто, но работает на всех сайтах, кроме mail.
Причем в условие заходит, если поставить туда какой-нибудь alert - все сработает, а вот window.close(), я думаю(так как web - не мой профиль), отлавливается самим сайтом и отрубается.

Внимание вопрос: как закрыть вкладку, если в ее адресе содержится "go.mail"?

Comment: `location.hostname == 'go.mail.ru'`? Корневое окно нельзя скриптом закрыть, только те, которые были... порождены :) "Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by it." Если использовать расширения для браузера, то там можно многое творить. И закрывать, конечно, тоже (если разрешение есть).

Comment: то есть придется написать свое расширение? Меня собственно волнует любой другой вариант событий, который будет решать мою задачу.

Comment: Угу. У хрома отличный и лёгкий API для управления вкладками, в другие браузеры особо не вникал.